# User.Identity and related attributes - how can I process them in a single method that can be called by any of my controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

User.Identity can be accessed in a controller of course. But I don't want to have every controller have a copied method to grab user common attributes.

```
public class myClass
{
  public void myMethod()
  {    //assume user is authenticated for the purposes of this question 
        var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();           
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var currentUser = manager.FindById(currentUserId);
        ViewBag.UserID = currentUser.Id;
        ViewBag.favoriteColor = currentUser.favoriteColor;            
  }
}
```

What is a good way to do this so that it is accessible by all of my controllers? Where would I put it and how would I call it and what might I have to pass it to make it work, in a best practices sort of way?

Comment: I originally posed this question, including in the title, about setting ViewBag variables in a single method called by my different controllers. My research today suggests that ViewBag variables cannot be accessed away from the controller class that created them. My actual intent with the initial post was to be able to access User.Identity info from a single class from my different controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..ovveride your controller with base controller

```
  public class BaseController : Controller
    {
       public YOUR_MODEL User{ get; set; }
       protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
          if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
              {
                var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();           
                var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
                var currentUser = manager.FindById(currentUserId);
                User.UserID = currentUser.Id;
                User.favoriteColor = currentUser.favoriteColor;     
              }
        }
   }
```

Your Controller

```
 public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
      //Here you can directly use User.UserId or User.favouriteColor
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this and I get a yellow page error on my browser: "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." In fact if I clear the code within the Initialize override I get the same error.  Also, the public YOUR_MODEL User{ get; set; } line seems unnecessary and not useful as it is the existing IPrincipal User that I want to use, though I may be missing your point here.  Anyway, thank you for your idea which seemed clever. Please let me know if I am missing some point here.

Comment: I will note that the blowup occurs after it leaves the override Initialize code. Curious to me is the fact that if I have User.Identity.IsAuthenticated in the code rather than Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated, it blows up on that.

Answer (score 0):

My goal was getting User.Identity information from a class outside of the several controllers I have so that the code would not be duplicated.

What I just came up with is as follows (isApproved, isLockedOut, and memberID fields are my own entries into the AspNetUsers table):

```
public class MyClass
{
   public string getMemberID(System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal User)//Note that this is the same name as is passed in, just personal preference       
    {

        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            if (currentUserId == null)
            {
               return "0";
            }
            else
            {
                var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
                var currentUser = manager.FindById(currentUserId);

                if (currentUser.isApproved && !currentUser.isLockedOut)
                    return  currentUser.memberID.ToString();
                else
                   return "0";
            }
        }
        else
            return "0";
    }
}
```

And it is called from the controller with this:

```
 string memberID =   MyClass.getMemberID(User);
```

---

Getting the intended parameter type was my original problem.  But then I experimented and created the following code:

```
var myUser = User;
var currentUserId = myUser.Identity.GetUserId();//Refactor: Extract Method for this line.
```

Then I selected the second line and did a Refactor; Extract Method. The result was that I learned what type to pass and how to call it.